# rendering zend form elements leaves a whitespace before

Tags: php, zend-form, whitespace, element, render

When I manually echo zend_form_elements (created through Form creation from an ini file), it appears that some whitespace is left before the actual element and I can't understand whats causing it or how to fix it. The direction is right to left btw.  The screenshot describes best what I mean: (The 1 to 5 fields are form elements after removing the label decorator)

http://i52.tinypic.com/orqbkz.jpg

Here's the php code:

```
$templateElems = '<ol id=elemlist><li>'.$removeButton.'</li>';
        foreach ($elements as $elem){
        /*  $elem->label_style='';*/
            $elem->setLabel('');
            $elem->removeDecorator('label');
            $templateElems = $templateElems.'<li>'.$elem.'</li>';
            $table =  $table.'<th>'.$elem->getName().'</th>';
```

I would be most grateful if someone could at least tell me whats causing those whitespaces.
Thanks in advance!
Here's the HTML as requested:

```
   <input type=hidden id=oldnum name=num value=0></input>
<input type=hidden id=newnum name=num value=0></input>
<ol id=elemlist>
<li><img src="/images/delete.png" id=remitem name="remitem"></img></li>
<li><dd id="name-element"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""></dd></li><li><dd id="text1-element"><input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value=""></dd></li><li><dd id="text2-element"><input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" value=""></dd></li><li><dd id="num1-element"><input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" value=""></dd></li>
</ol>
<table id=items border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="list">
<tr><th>Remove Item</th><th>name</th><th>text1</th><th>text2</th><th>num1</th></tr>
</table>
<button id=addnew type="button">הוסף פריט</button></fieldset>
<dt id="submit-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="submit-element">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="שלח"></dd></form></div>   
        <!--// End CONTENT-->
```

Comment: Hi, can you add the generated HTML of your form?

Comment: Looks like your output HTML is missing the body rows (the ones with `<td>`s) for the table. What happened to them?

Comment: They are not missing, they are added once the user clicks the addnew button - it triggers jquery that iterates through the list, wraps each element in td tags, all of them in tr and adds the row to the table. I didn't specify this part because when I saw that the result of the php script has those whitespaces, I concluded that it has nothing to do with javascript part. Sorry for confusion...

Answer (score 0):

I would set  the decorators to this:
$elem->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors'));

this line will remove the  tags that are created around your text box and it will remove the spaces.

Comment: I considered doing that and that is probably what I will do in the end if I dont find another solution. The problem with this is that I won't be able to use decorators at all in this case..

Comment: humm, in that case set the dd tag in your css file to have no margins or paddings

Comment: like this:
dd {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help and sorry for not responding for so long with the results. I inspected the default css for dd tags and the next property appeared there:
-webkit-margin-start: 40px;
I changed it to 0 and now its fine it seems.